# JTextArea height is only 1 line when using GridBayLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am doing a program that finds words in a text file. I am using GridBagLayout for the position of the elements. When I run the program the text area shows with just one line. Even though it is set `JTextArea results = new JTextArea(30, 30)`

This is what it shows at the moment:
[image]

I am trying to do something like this:
[image]

Java code:

```
public class WordFinder extends JFrame {

    private WordList words = new WordList();

    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 380;    
    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 380;  
    private static final int TEXT_WIDTH = 30; 

    private JLabel findLabel = new JLabel("Find:"); 
    private JLabel wordsContaining = new JLabel("words containing");    
    private JTextField findWord = new JTextField(TEXT_WIDTH);
    private JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
    private JTextArea results = new JTextArea(30, 30);
    private JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(results);
    private JFileChooser chooseFile = new JFileChooser();
    private JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    public WordFinder() {

        super("Word Finder");

        // Initialize the menu bar
        //initMenu();

        results.setEditable(false);

        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        pane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(15, 20, 0, 10));
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        results.setLineWrap(true);
        results.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        scroll.setViewportView(results);

        // Add label "Find"
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(findLabel, c);

        // Add text field
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(findWord, c);

        // Add clear button
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = .1;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(clear, c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 0);
        pane.add(wordsContaining, c);

        // Add text area
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 3, 0, 5);
        pane.add(scroll, c);

        add(pane);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run () {
                new WordFinder().show();
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Any ideas in what am I missing? or perhaps I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Instead of `setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);`, try using `pack()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Change `c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;` to `c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;`
2. Use `pack` instead of `setSize`

For example

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class WordFinder extends JFrame {

    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 380;
    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 380;
    private static final int TEXT_WIDTH = 30;

    private JLabel findLabel = new JLabel("Find:");
    private JLabel wordsContaining = new JLabel("words containing");
    private JTextField findWord = new JTextField(TEXT_WIDTH);
    private JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
    private JTextArea results = new JTextArea(30, 30);
    private JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(results);
    private JFileChooser chooseFile = new JFileChooser();
    private JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    public WordFinder() {

        super("Word Finder");

                // Initialize the menu bar
        //initMenu();
        results.setEditable(false);

        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        pane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(15, 20, 0, 10));
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        results.setLineWrap(true);
        results.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        scroll.setViewportView(results);

        // Add label "Find"
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(findLabel, c);

        // Add text field
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(findWord, c);

        // Add clear button
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = .1;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(clear, c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 0);
        pane.add(wordsContaining, c);

        // Add text area
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 3, 0, 5);
        pane.add(scroll, c);

        add(pane);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new WordFinder().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem you're having is caused by a combination of using the `fill` property `GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL` and `setSize`.  When you use `setSize`, the size of the container is smaller then the `JScrollPane'`s `preferredSize` and the layout manager is resorting to it's `minimumSize` instead.

By using `GridBagConstraints.BOTH`, you are allowing the layout manager to expand the component to fill the entire available space of the cell, regardless

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry, I'll try and limit myself ... I wish ;)

Comment: It's a damn addiction.